# Can I get an outlet from this section of the open wall?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, vanity

There is a hole in one of the cabinets of the vanity, and I'd like to see if I can get an outlet installed through here. As a newbie who's never done electrical work, is it safe, and possible?

[image: Hole behind the vanity]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you take advantage of this hole to install an outlet nearby?  Yes probably.  The hole would probably make it easier to bring a cable to this location, and you could install an outlet in a surface-mount box inside the cabinet, or through a new hole cut for the purpose nearby in the back of the cabinet.

The harder question is where would the cable come *from*?  You need to tap off an existing outlet or your electrical panel and route a cable from there.  That needs some exploration and planning on your part.

Is it safe for a newbie to add an outlet in a wall?  IMO this is not a good first project, and is unlikely to be done safely without some on-site tutoring from someone knowledgeable.  There are too many details you need to learn in order to purchase the right materials and install them the right way.  If you have someone skilled who can watch and guide you, this could be safe but then you'd probably be asking them, not us.

Comment: Appreciate the response, and yes, due to it being a first time electrical project, I think I'll get an opinion of an EE friend and see if he can help out if anything.

Comment: No offense to any EEs out there, but in this case, somebody with experience fishing wires around plumbing is more valuable.

Comment: ↑ @AloysiusDefenestrate - heartily agree. Just today had to defer to my friend's son, a mere snip of a lad [22] who successfully fished 240v mains & water through a [laughingly called] crawlspace 6" high over 30 ft to a 2" hole on an outside wall, passing all existing water, gas & power… without lifting a single floorboard. Pro job.

Comment: @Tetsujin in that situation I just swear a lot, and if that doesn't work, I swear some more, and eventually the job gets done. :)

Comment: @jay613 - I was busy swearing at something else while he got on with that ;)) Both jobs got done.